# problema con archivos en C

Tags: c

tengo el siguiente problema...

Tengo una Lista en C y sus funciones,osea Esta el menú con las opciones de:Ingresar elemento al inicio,ingresar elemento al final,borrar elemento,borrar lista,buscar elemento...etc etc etc son varias.

> Codigo

```
int usuario,id;
NODO *nuevo=(NODO*)malloc(sizeof(NODO));//creamos un nuevo nodo y ese nuevo nodo es apuntado por nuevo
//printf("ingrese el numero:");
//  scanf("%d",&usuario); ESTO NO PORQUE AHORA SE IMPORTARAN LOS DATOS DESDE UN ARCHIVO
f = fopen ("datos.txt", "rb+");
if (f == NULL){
    perror("Erro de leer archivo");
    return 1;
}
if (!feof(f)){
    fscanf (f,"%i",&id);
//  printf("%i \n",id);
    fflush(stdin);   
    }
usuario = id;

fclose(f);
nuevo->siguiente=NULL;
nuevo->num=usuario;
printf("\n");
*temp=nuevo;
```

}

Ahora,el problema esta cuando quiero leer los datos ya que los debo importar desde un archivo... 
La estructura del archivo es de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el primer elemento lo lee y lo inserta bien, pero cuando regreso al menú principal y vuelvo a seleccionar la opción de insertar elemento este inserta el mismo primer elemento. Al parecer el cursor se vuelve al inicio del archivo cuando sale de la función, hay alguna manera de que el cursor se quede en el fin da la linea del ultimo dato que leyó para que cuando vuelva a seleccionar la opción de insertar elemento seleccione el elemento siguiente y así.

Tengo ganas de meter todo en un arreglo y lo manejo desde allí, pero no le veo el chiste de usar un archivo si lo hago con un arreglo xD

Comment: Aclaro que el código que muestro es el de crear un nodo para mas adelante insertarlo dependiendo donde seleccione el usuario

Comment: debes agregar la función que tiene problema, para que ver donde existe alguna falla en el código, para poder ayudarte

Answer (score -1):

Creo que reabres el archivo en la función para insertar el elemento, lo que deberías hacer es, o no abrir el archivo cada vez en la función o guardar la última posición en la que se abrió el archivo y luego utilizar fseek (una función dentro de c) para posicionar el archivo en la siguiente posición a la guardada.

Te dejo una página que te puede ayudar: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek